# Adding a pop up menu in .net Maui

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, maui

[image: screenshot of pop up menu on iOS]

I’m trying to figure out 1) what this kind of menu is called 2) how I can add one to my app in .net Maui.

This is a screenshot from the twitter iOS app. Every tweet has an ellipses button that contains this pop up menu that lets perform actions with the tweet or the author. I’d like to add something similar to my app but I’m having trouble figuring out what this is called.

Comment: https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups